# Sign of a symbolic algebraic expression

Tags: algorithm, algebra, computer-algebra-systems

Is there any algorithm that can find the sign of an arbitrary symbolic algebraic expression given in a "Tree - Form"?

I know that a general algorithm doesn't exist because the zero recognizion problem is undecidable for an arbitrary expression, but how should I approach the problem of finding the sign of an expression?
(how is this done in computer algebra?)

For example: `sign(sqrt(2)-1) = ?`

Comment: When you say "algebraic", does it contain unknowns?

Comment: No, it is free of variables. Also, when I said "algebraic" I didn't mean it could only contain algeraic numbers. It could also contain something like log(2) or atan(2).But I'm not looking for a general algorithm.

Comment: You should evaluate the expression with sufficient precision. You probably want to use an arbitrary precision arithmetic package, and possibly interval arithmetic on top of that.

Comment: I was thinking of that, but what if the number is so small that it evaluates to numerical "0". A bigger problem is that the evaluation of an expression to some precision takes time (sometimes too much time)

Comment: Some problems are numericaly difficult and you will not get through this easily (if you do at all). If the numbers are so close to 0, that differences may be smaller than machine-epsilon, I believe there may not be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Evaluate the function value**

You need function evaluator engine for that  (it is not that hard to code) there is **no way** to evaluate **sign only** if you want to **support +,-** operations !!! All my function evaluators works like this:

1. **compile the source text of the function**

   First create supported functions table (id,num of operands,name,pointer to function) like:

   ```
   +,-,*,/,sin,cos,....
   ```

   These will be the building blocks to any supported expression you need to evaluate. Do not forget to code all functions in your code too. Handle brackets `(`,`)` also as functions (`push,pop`). Group your functions by number of operands so `+,-` are with 1 and 2 operands (two different functions each !!!).

   Now from expression extract:

   - variable names
   - constant names and values
   - number values

   Into some kind of table/list:

   ```
   variables[](id,name,value)
   constants[](id,name,value)
   numbers  [](id,    ,value)
   ```

   And now finally construct compiled function string. My strings are set of two `int`'s. First is `type` (which table to use) and second is `id` (index in table).

   for example expression:

   ```
   sign(sqrt(2)-1)
   ```

   **types:**

   ```
   id type
   0  function
   1  number
   2  constant
   3  variable
   ```

   **functions:**

   ```
   id name   pointer
   0  '('    ???
   1  ')'    ???
   2  '+'    ???
   3  '-'    ???
   4  '*'    ???
   5  '/'    ???
   6  'sqrt' ???
   7  'sign' ???
   ```

   There are no **variables** or **constants**. The **numbers** are:

   ```
   id value
   0  2  
   1  1
   ```

   **compiled string:**

   ```
   type id
   0    7   // sign(1 operand)
   0    6   // sqrt(1 operand)
   1    0   // 2
   0    3   // - (2 operands)
   1    1   // 1
   ```
2. **After compilation you need to interpret the string and evaluate it's value.**

   1. init variables

      ```
      op1=0`,`op2=0, // set all operands to zero (number depends on supported functions usually 2)
      opn=0          // actual operands number
      fx=none        // actual function (for example none=-1)
      fxn=0          // actual function operands number
      ```
   2. read first record of compiled string

      if it is value (number,constant,variable) set appropriate `op?` value with it and increment operand counter `opn++`.

      if it is function set `fx,fxn` code with it
   3. if `opn == fxn`

      You reached needed operand count so execute function `fx` and init next function

      ```
      op1=fxtab[fx].pointer(op1,op2,...)
      fx=none,fxn=1
      opn=1  (some spec functions can return more operands, then set op1,op2,.. opn=...)
      ```
   4. if not end of string goto **#2** but with next string record
   5. at the end `op1` should hold your output value

**some example functions (C++ implementation):**

```
double sign(double op1) 
 { 
 if (op1>0.0) return +1.0; 
 if (op1<0.0) return -1.0; 
 return 0.0; 
 }
double sqrt1(double op1) { return sqrt(op1); }
double plus1(double op1) { return op1; }
double minus1(double op1) { return -op1; }
double plus2(double op1,double op2) { return op1+op2; }
double minus2(double op1,double op2) { return op1-op2; }
```

**[Notes]**

You have to handle special cases like `function = "";`. Also beware spacing, case sensitivity because any error in compilation invalidates the result.

**Speed is not a big issue this is interpreting-evaluation not numerical solution**. All operations are called the same times as you would do on the paper.

You should also handle mathematic errors (overflows,invalid operands,`NaN`,`Inf` ...)

I usually group functions with the same number of operands to own type to simplify things

Comment: I have already a numerical and symbolic parser for String expressions. However I want to know how this is done in Computer Algebra (like Mathematica or Maple). Is this really done by the numerical value of an expression?

Comment: I think that YES, because if you have addition or substraction in the formula then the sign is defined by both the sign and values of the operands ... so I see no other way to do that sign determination