# How to convert a string mathematical expression into a BigInteger?

Tags: android, math, biginteger

A part of the goal in my app is to receive a mathematical expression (e.g. `1 + 1`) by string, and convert it to a `BigInteger`.
My goal is to have an equivalent to:

```
BigInteger result = new BigInteger("1+1");
// This will throw an exception of invalid BigInteger
```

Also, `ScriptEngineManager` class isn't available for Android.
I still cannot find a way to achieve my goal.
Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: What have you tried so far. Please provide code that you used to achieve what you describe.

Comment: I said, I couldn't find a way to achieve this.

Comment: Your definition of "mathematical expression" is unclear. What is included, what is excluded? You should give a precise definition and describe the problem exactly, otherwise there are many ways to interpret and answer your question...

Comment: google "expression evaluation" .. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20919547/2521214) is how I do it

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
//If you have to parse only the result
String result = "2";

BigInteger.valueOf(Long.valueOf("2");

//If you have to parse the whole operation
String result = "1+1";
//create an algo to extract each 1 and determine operation

BigInteger bigIntUn = new BigInteger("1");
BigInteger bigIntAnotherUn = new BigInteger("1");

//you have add (+), min(-), multiply(*) (etc...)
bigIntUn.add(bigIntAnotherUn);
```

Comment: My goal is to have an equivalent to `BigInteger result = new BigInteger("1+1");`